# Как записать все найденные характеристики товаров в отдельные столбцы excel?

Tags: python, парсер

Помогите пожалуйста понять. Пишу первый парсер. Написал функцию добавления данных парсинга в excel так, чтобы по первому товару, названия характеристик записывались в заголовки столбцов, но как только парсер натыкается на характеристику, которой нет в первом товаре, происходит ошибка:

```
ValueError: 'Емкость лотка автоподатчика' is not in list
```

Как добавить эту характеристику в общий список столбцов и последующую тоже.

Мой код:

```py
def dump_to_xlsx(OUT_XLSX_FILENAME, listing):
    if not len(listing):
        return None
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook(OUT_XLSX_FILENAME) as workbook:
        ws = workbook.add_worksheet()
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
        headers = ['Название товара', 'Артикул', 'Цена', 'Картинка', 'Описание']
        headers.extend(listing[0]['props'])

        for col, h in enumerate(headers):
            ws.write_string(0, col, h, cell_format = bold)

        for row, item in enumerate(listing, start=1):
            ws.write_string(row, 0, item['name'])
            ws.write_string(row, 1, item['article'])
            ws.write_string(row, 2, item['price'])
            ws.write_string(row, 3, item['url_img'])
            ws.write_string(row, 4, item['description'])
            for prop_name, prop_value in item['props'].items():
                col = headers.index(prop_name)
                ws.write_string(row, col, prop_value)
```

Пробовал вот такую конструкцию, чтобы присвоить col недостающее значение, но ошибка сохраняется:

```py
for prop_name, prop_value in item['props'].items():
   if listing[0]['props'] not in headers:
        col = listing[0]['props']
   col = headers.index(prop_name)
   ws.write_string(row, col, prop_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что `listing` это массив словарей, в которых должен быть ключ `props`. А в свою очередь `props` так же является словарем. Строчкой ниже, вы добавляется в `headers` ключи из словаря `listing[0]['props']`. Это нужно понимать для дальнейшего объяснения.

```py
headers.extend(listing[0]['props'])
```

Вот ваша попытка с моими комментариями, что происходит:

```py
for prop_name, prop_value in item['props'].items():
   # listing[0]['props'] это словарь и вы проверяете, нет ли его в headers
   # очевидно его нет (по причине описанной в ответе выше)
   if listing[0]['props'] not in headers:
        # По этому эта строчка никогда не будет выполнена
        # Но и тут вы не понятно, что хотели сделать
        # Присваиваете col, который должен быть индексом колонки словарь
        col = listing[0]['props']
   # Находим индекс prop_name в headers
   col = headers.index(prop_name)
   ws.write_string(row, col, prop_value)
```

Даже если, строчка `col = listing[0]['props']` будет выполнена, сразу следующей строчкой, вы пытаетесь `col` присвоить новое значение. То есть смысла от `if` просто нет. Он по факту ничего не делает.

Как я понял из вопроса, на основе первого товара у вас устанавливаются `headers` и вам нужно у следующих товаров из `props` брать только те значения, чьи ключи есть в `headers` (или в `listing[0]['props']` т.к. первые 5 элементов вы добавляете отдельно, по этому предполагается, что они 100% существуют).

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```py
# Проходимся по характеристикам первого товара
for index, prop_name in enumerate(listing[0]['props']):
    # Если характеристики первого товара, нет в рассматрвиаемом
    # то просто идем дальше
    if prop_name not in item['props']:
        continue
    # Если же есть, то берем её значение и записываем его
    # 5 + index - означает, что столбец для записи будет начинаться с 5
    # т.к. до этого вы уже записали 5 значений по столбцам
    ws.write_string(row, 5 + index, item['props'][prop_name])
```